# How to show nested list in Class in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have made two classes - example for this question only:

```
public class Item
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Item() { }

    public Item(int itemId, string name) 
    {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class GroupOfitems
{
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public List<Item> itemList;

    public GroupOfitems()
    {
        itemList = new List<Item>();
    }

    public GroupOfitems(string groupName, List<Item> itemList)
    {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }
}

public List<GroupOfitems> TestMethod()
{
    // ADD SOME ITEMS TO FRUIT GROUP
    List<Item> bla = new List<Item>();
    bla.Add(new Item(1, "Banana"));
    bla.Add(new Item(2, "Apple"));

    // ADD SOME ITEMS TO VEGETABLES GROUP
    List<Item> bla2 = new List<Item>();
    bla2.Add(new Item(5, "Carot"));
    bla2.Add(new Item(6, "Tomato"));

    // ADD SOME ITEMS TO SOURCE
    List<GroupOfitems> result = new List<GroupOfitems>();
    result.Add(new GroupOfitems("Fruit", bla));
    result.Add(new GroupOfitems("Vegetables", bla2));

    // RETURN SOURCE
    return result;  
}
```

And in my .aspx file I have `ObjectDataSource` and `ListView` like:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsRecipesIngredientListTest" runat="server"
    SelectMethod="TestMethod" TypeName="MyRepository">            
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ListView ID="lvRecipeIngredients" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="odsRecipesIngredientListTest" 
    ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolderId">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceHolderId" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGroupName" Text='<%# Eval("groupName") %>' runat="server" /><br />

        <asp:ListView ID="lvIngredientList" runat="server" 
            DataSource='<%# Eval("itemList") %>' 
            ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolderId">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceHolderId" runat="server" />
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("itemId") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label16" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

This is a really quick example for this question. Eveything works fine but I just can't bind `itemList` like a `DataSource` to nested `ListView` like (`DataSource='<%# Eval("itemList") %>'`) (because `itemList` is not a property in class). Is this the right approach for binding or do I need to change my approach?

Comment: Have you tried nested repeater control?

Comment: I don`t think that nested listview is a problem. I will try it now but I think that the DataSource like List<Item> itemList list is not the right way ... I will try with repeater and give here a comment about it

Comment: Like I said, the same error - DataBinding: MyRepository ... datasource GRoupOfItems does not contains a property with name itemList ... It bind groupName property like it should but cant find itemlist like property because it is not property...

Comment: Please try to make `GroupOfItems::itemList` a property: `public List<Item> ItemList { get; private set; }`.

Comment: Hehe I can`t belive it that I missed this :P This works for my example, so post it like an answer... I can`t belive it that I didn`t see this :P

Comment: Now I just need to find the best way that I would retrive data from database like this ... because now I am getting data in rows like groupName, itemId, name .... but I need to join them by groupName like example above. If I could manage that with one stored procedure or entity framework this would be great...

Comment: @janilemy: I've posted the answer... your last question different from what's beeing asked here. You should create a new one. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `listItems` member is defined as *field*, not as *property*, preventing the reflection to find it using [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kyaxdd3x.aspx) (which is, what data binding actually does).

```
public class GroupOfitems
{
    public string groupName { get; private set; }

    public List<Item> ItemList { get; private set; }

    public GroupOfitems()
    {
        this.ItemList = new List<Item>();
    }

    public GroupOfitems(string groupName, List<Item> itemList)
    {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.ItemList = itemList;
    }
}
```

In fact you should always use properties to expose your data interface. That's what meant by [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).